# Java unique file id fileKey : Path -> fileKey OK | fileKey -> Path possible?

Tags: java

Ok,

So i can get a beautiful unique file key for a given file:

http://openjdk.java.net/projects/nio/javadoc/java/nio/file/attribute/BasicFileAttributes.html

But can one get the whereabouts (Path) of a file, given a fileKey?

Comment: @JoshM How do you use that when you only have a `fileKey`?

Comment: It doesn't seem like that's possible. On Windows, `fileKey()` always returns `null`. On linux, it returns a [package access class](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7u40-b43/sun/nio/fs/UnixFileAttributes.java?av=h#UnixFileAttributes.UnixAsBasicFileAttributes) so it can't really be used anywhere else.

Comment: Yeah, nah, it looks like not doable, even thought it would be really cool to keep track of a file even if a user moves it.